# set Value to Jformattedtextfield using MaskFormatter in java

Tags: java, swing

I have a MaskFormatter and Jformattedtextfield .The code for that is

```
try {
    mk = new MaskFormatter("**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**");
    mk.setPlaceholderCharacter('_');
} catch(ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

format1=new JFormattedTextField(mk);
format1.setBounds(170, 80, 280,25);
format1.setFont(new Font("serif",Font.PLAIN,13));
commandpanel.add(format1);
```

I have added maskformatter to jformattedTextfield.On click of a button i am trying to set a value to format1 but nothing is getting displayed in format1 field.

This is the code for setting the value

```
// value may be 1E0234
String value=hashmap1.get("Command 1").substring(hashmap1.get("Command 1").lastIndexOf("-")+2, hashmap1.get("Command 1").length());

format1.setValue(value);
```

I also tried with format1.setText(value),in this case it is displaying in the field but without a maskformatter.

How do i display the value along with the mask.

Comment: It would be easier if we could see what is the value of `hashmap1.get("Command 1").substring(hashmap1.get("Command 1").lastIndexOf("-")+2, hashmap1.get("Command 1").length())`

Comment: Might be different issues. Try to isolate the problem. Does it happen when you use a simple JTextField? Might want to try a simpler format first in MaskFormatter before doing such a long one.

Comment: with the simple JTextField it is displaying properly. But with JFormattedtextfield it is not displaying

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I do not see how `1E0234` fits `**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**`.

Comment: i tried with **-**-** also but not working

Comment: sorry i tried with (**-**-**) also

Comment: Will it work if you try to enter `ZZ-99-ZZ-99-ZZ-99-ZZ-99-ZZ-99-ZZ-99-ZZ-99-ZZ` as value ?

Comment: i tried but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public class MyJFrame extends JFrame {

MyJFrame() {
    try {
        MaskFormatter mk = null;
        try {
            mk = new MaskFormatter("**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**");
            mk.setPlaceholderCharacter('_');
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JFormattedTextField format1 = new JFormattedTextField(mk);
        format1.setBounds(170, 80, 280, 25);
        format1.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        String value = "ZZ-99-ZZ-99-ZZ-99-ZZ-99-ZZ-99-ZZ-99-ZZ-99-ZZ";//hashmap1.get("Command 1").substring(hashmap1.get("Command 1").lastIndexOf("-")+2, hashmap1.get("Command 1").length());
        String display = mk.valueToString(value);
        System.out.println("display = " + display);
        format1.setValue(value);
        add(format1);
        pack();
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MyJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MyJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

If value is "zz-99" it displays

```
zz-99-__-__-__-__-__-__-__-__-__-__-__-__-__
```

Comment: what if value is only zz-99 as maskformatter is same as above.

Comment: it is possible to display only zz-99

Comment: Ow, @WillShacklenford, we happend to shoot the code at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you are trying to enter a value the field can't handle. You need to find the way to make your values fit the format you want. Good luck with that.

This works for me

```
public class FormattedTextFieldTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(); // default flow layout
            frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
            MaskFormatter mk = new MaskFormatter("**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**");
            JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(mk);
            contentPane.add(field);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            // Doesnt work
            //field.setValue("1E0234");
            //field.setValue("ZZ99ZZ99ZZ99ZZ99ZZ99ZZ99ZZ99");

            // Works for me
            field.setValue("1E-02-34");
            //field.setValue("ZZ-99-ZZ-99-ZZ-99-ZZ-99-ZZ-99-ZZ-99-ZZ-99");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

(**Postdata**)
I notice there is already [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32046533/1117429) (which got all the credit). Apparently both provide working code and mine is apparently posterior. Why should I keep it?

- I was troubleshooting the question in the comments **before** any answer was posted. It was me who prompted the OP for the actual value, **which was the actual problem** . It was unfortunate that the other guy jumped over my shoulders and got all the credit while I was prompting why "ZZ-99 ..." was not accepted (the OP claimed it did not work, but **IT SHOULD** , as the example shows), and then the other guy posted just the minute I had my working example.
- My answers has some distinct virtues that the accepted answer does not. **First** it clearly shows which values are accepted and which not, which **does a better job at answering the question**. And less important **second** it does not leave a zombie process when you close the frame, and **third** it is more clean from stuff unrelated to the problem.
- If anyone at this point has any reason why I should remove my answer, please comment before downvoting.