# Set value in a JFormattedTextField with mask

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

I have a `JFormattedTextField` that has a mask (`##/##/####`, a date).
I want to set the value of the formattedTextField but this instructions doesn't work:

```
dbirthFormattedField.setValue(FormattedDate);
```

where `FormattedDate` is a String that match with the mask of the jFormattedTextField.

After the setValue instruction, the text in the jFormattedField become empty and i can't reinitialize it.

Any advice?

Comment: Possible dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045576/set-value-to-jformattedtextfield-using-maskformatter-in-java

Comment: the formattedField isn't a created by a SimpleDataObject but in this way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TMMVC5Fzxg

Comment: Instead jFormattedTextField you should use jxdatepicker from swingx library